# How to delete item from ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

In my application, I have 2 `recyclerview` into one activity. 
I want when to add items in one `recyclerview', add this item into other`recyclerview`.

In 2 `recyclerViews` for send data to activity I use `Interface`.

But when click on items in `recyclerview` two show me error in **Logcat**.

**Activity codes:**

```
public class SuggestFilmActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SuggestedListener, SuggestedDeleteListener {

    @BindView(R.id.toolbarTitleTxt)
    TextView toolbarTitleTxt;
    @BindView(R.id.suggestFilm_searchEditText)
    EditText suggestFilm_searchEditText;
    @BindView(R.id.suggestFilm_searchBtn)
    ImageView suggestFilm_searchBtn;
    @BindView(R.id.suggestFilm_clearBtn)
    ImageView suggestFilm_clearBtn;
    @BindView(R.id.suggestFilm_recyclerView)
    RecyclerView suggestFilm_recyclerView;
    @BindView(R.id.suggestFilm_recyclerViewProgress)
    ProgressBar suggestFilm_recyclerViewProgress;
    @BindView(R.id.suggestFilm_noDataText)
    TextView suggestFilm_noDataText;
    @BindView(R.id.newsPageLoadLay)
    RelativeLayout newsPageLoadLay;
    @BindView(R.id.suggestFilm_recyclerViewSendUser)
    RecyclerView suggestFilm_recyclerViewSendUser;
    @BindView(R.id.suggestFilm_buttonsSendCard)
    CardView suggestFilm_buttonsSendCard;
    private Context context;
    private SuggestFilmAdapter suggestFilmAdapter;
    private List<Result> model = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<SuggestFilmAddUser> suggestFilmAddUserList = new ArrayList<>();
    private SuggestFilmUserAdapter suggestFilmUserAdapter;
    private InterfaceApi api;
    private SharedPrefrencesHandler prefrencesHandler;
    private String token;
    private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private List<Integer> usersListSend = new ArrayList<>();
    private SuggestFilmAddUser suggestFilmAddUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_suggest_film);
        //Initialize
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        context = this;
        prefrencesHandler = new SharedPrefrencesHandler(context);
        api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
        suggestFilmAdapter = new SuggestFilmAdapter(context, model, this);
        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 3);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        //Get token
        token = prefrencesHandler.getFromShared(SharedPrefrencesKeys.TOKEN.name());
        //Set toolbar title
        toolbarTitleTxt.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.SuggestToFollowers));
        //Init followers recyclerView
        suggestFilm_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        suggestFilm_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        //Init send user recyclerView
        suggestFilm_recyclerViewSendUser.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        suggestFilm_recyclerViewSendUser.setHasFixedSize(true);
        //Init Send user adapter
        suggestFilmUserAdapter = new SuggestFilmUserAdapter(context, suggestFilmAddUserList, this);
        suggestFilm_recyclerViewSendUser.setAdapter(suggestFilmUserAdapter);
        //Load more
        newsPageLoadLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        suggestFilm_recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerGridPage1(gridLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {

                newsPageLoadLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Call<SeriesWhoWatchedResponse> call = api.getSuggestFilmUsers(token, filmSendData("", 10, current_page));

                call.enqueue(new Callback<SeriesWhoWatchedResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<SeriesWhoWatchedResponse> call, Response<SeriesWhoWatchedResponse> response) {
                        if (response.body().getData() != null && response.body().getStatusCode() != 401
                                && response.body().getStatusCode() != 402) {
                            if (response.body().getData().getResult().size() > 0) {
                                suggestFilmAdapter.addNewItem(response.body().getData().getResult());
                                //Gone no explore
                                newsPageLoadLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        } else {
                            prefrencesHandler.remove(SharedPrefrencesKeys.TOKEN.name());
                            startActivity(new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class));
                        }

                        newsPageLoadLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<SeriesWhoWatchedResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        newsPageLoadLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        //Get user data
        getUserData("", 1);
    }

    private void getUserData(String search, int page) {
        suggestFilm_recyclerViewProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Call<SeriesWhoWatchedResponse> call = api.getSuggestFilmUsers(token, filmSendData(search, 10, page));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<SeriesWhoWatchedResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SeriesWhoWatchedResponse> call, Response<SeriesWhoWatchedResponse> response) {
                if (response.body().getData() != null) {
                    if (response.body().getData().getResult().size() > 0) {
                        model.clear();
                        model.addAll(response.body().getData().getResult());
                        suggestFilmAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        suggestFilm_recyclerView.setAdapter(suggestFilmAdapter);
                        suggestFilm_noDataText.setText("");
                    } else {
                        model.clear();
                        suggestFilmAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        suggestFilm_recyclerView.setAdapter(suggestFilmAdapter);
                        suggestFilm_noDataText.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.noFollowersYet));
                    }
                }
                suggestFilm_recyclerViewProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SeriesWhoWatchedResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                suggestFilm_recyclerViewProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

    private SuggestFilmSendData filmSendData(String search, int size, int page) {
        SuggestFilmSendData sendData = new SuggestFilmSendData();
        sendData.setKeyword(search);
        sendData.setPageIndex(page);
        sendData.setPageSize(size);

        return sendData;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSend(int Id, String name, String image) {
        suggestFilmAddUser = new SuggestFilmAddUser();
        suggestFilmAddUser.setId(Id);
        suggestFilmAddUser.setName(name);
        suggestFilmAddUser.setImage(image);
        //Add to list only once item
        for (SuggestFilmAddUser idList : suggestFilmAddUserList) {
            if (idList.getId() == suggestFilmAddUser.getId()) {
                return;
            }
        }
        suggestFilmAddUserList.add(suggestFilmAddUser);
        if (suggestFilmAddUserList.size() > 0) {
            suggestFilm_buttonsSendCard.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));
            suggestFilm_buttonsSendCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    getSuggestList();
                }
            });
        }
        suggestFilmUserAdapter.notifyItemInserted(suggestFilmAddUserList.size() - 1);
        suggestFilm_recyclerViewSendUser.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        for (SuggestFilmAddUser suggest : suggestFilmAddUserList) {
            if (suggest.getId() == suggestFilmAddUser.getId()) {
                Log.e("SuggestLog", suggest.getId() + "");
                usersListSend.add(suggest.getId());
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDelete(int Id) {
        if (usersListSend.size() > 0) {
            usersListSend.remove(Id);
        }

        Toast.makeText(context, "" + Id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void getSuggestList() {
        for (SuggestFilmAddUser suggest : suggestFilmAddUserList) {
            if (suggest.getId() == suggestFilmAddUser.getId()) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "" + usersListSend, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

**For add user Adapter:**

```
public class SuggestFilmAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SuggestFilmAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Result> model;
    private SuggestedListener suggestedListener;

    public SuggestFilmAdapter(Context context, List<Result> model, SuggestedListener suggestedListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.model = model;
        this.suggestedListener = suggestedListener;
    }

    @Override
    public SuggestFilmAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_suggest_film_users_followers, parent, false);

        return new SuggestFilmAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SuggestFilmAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        //Name
        holder.row_suggestFilmProfileName.setText(model.get(position).getName());
        //Image
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(model.get(position).getImageUrl())
                .asBitmap()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .override(300, 300)
                .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(holder.row_suggestFilmProfileImage) {
                    @Override
                    protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                        if (context == null) return;

                        RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                                RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), resource);
                        circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
                        holder.row_suggestFilmProfileImage.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
                    }
                });
        //Is Mutual
        if (model.get(position).getIsMutual()) {
            holder.row_suggestFilmIsOk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.row_suggestFilmIsOk.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        holder.row_suggestedLay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                suggestedListener.onSend(model.get(position).getUserId(),
                        model.get(position).getName(),
                        model.get(position).getImageUrl());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return model.size();
    }

    public void addNewItem(List<Result> newContent) {
        int start = this.model.size();
        int end = newContent.size();
        model.addAll(newContent);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView row_suggestFilmProfileImage, row_suggestFilmIsOk;
        private TextView row_suggestFilmProfileName;
        private RelativeLayout row_suggestedLay;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            row_suggestFilmProfileImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_suggestFilmProfileImage);
            row_suggestFilmIsOk = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_suggestFilmIsOk);
            row_suggestFilmProfileName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_suggestFilmProfileName);
            row_suggestedLay = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_suggestedLay);
        }
    }
}
```

**For delete user adapter:**

```
public class SuggestFilmUserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SuggestFilmUserAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<SuggestFilmAddUser> model;
    private SuggestedDeleteListener deleteListener;

    public SuggestFilmUserAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SuggestFilmAddUser> model, SuggestedDeleteListener deleteListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.model = model;
        this.deleteListener = deleteListener;
    }

    @Override
    public SuggestFilmUserAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_suggest_film_users_add, parent, false);

        return new SuggestFilmUserAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SuggestFilmUserAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        //Name
        holder.rowSuggestAddUser_name.setText(model.get(position).getName());
        //Image
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(model.get(position).getImage())
                .asBitmap()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .override(300, 300)
                .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(holder.rowSuggestAddUser_image) {
                    @Override
                    protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                        if (context == null) return;

                        RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                                RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), resource);
                        circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
                        holder.rowSuggestAddUser_image.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
                    }
                });
        //Cancel btn
        holder.rowSuggestAddUser_cancelImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                deleteItem(position);
                deleteListener.onDelete(model.get(position).getId());
            }
        });
    }

    private void deleteItem(int position) {
        model.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, model.size());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return model.size();
    }

    public void addNewItem(ArrayList<SuggestFilmAddUser> newContent) {
        int start = this.model.size();
        int end = newContent.size();
        model.addAll(newContent);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView rowSuggestAddUser_image, rowSuggestAddUser_cancelImage;
        private TextView rowSuggestAddUser_name;
        private RelativeLayout rowSuggestAddUser_lay;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            rowSuggestAddUser_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowSuggestAddUser_image);
            rowSuggestAddUser_cancelImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowSuggestAddUser_cancelImage);
            rowSuggestAddUser_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowSuggestAddUser_name);
            rowSuggestAddUser_lay = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowSuggestAddUser_lay);
        }
    }
}
```

**LogCat error :**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.app.test, PID: 28516
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 18, size is 2
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:403)
at com.app.test.Activities.SuggestFilmActivity.onDelete(SuggestFilmActivity.java:222)
at com.app.test.Adapters.SuggestFilm.SuggestFilmUserAdapter$2.onClick(SuggestFilmUserAdapter.java:76)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4764)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19844)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

**Show error for this line in onDelete:**

```
usersListSend.remove(Id);
```

Please help me, I am amateur and really need this help. please . Thanks, all <3

Comment: The error said `IndexOutOfBounds` so you are giving a bad index value obviously, so the given position in `OnBindViewHolder` is certainly not the one you are looking for !

Comment: @JoachimHuet, can you help me for fix this error? please my bro. really need your help

Comment: why passing ID in place of position 

deleteListener.onDelete(model.get(position).getId());

Comment: @ArbazRizvi, I want when user click on deleteAdapter, delete users from this list. for this I send ID with interface . can you help me?

Comment: usersListSend.remove(Id); Here you have pass position instead of ID.

Comment: Check my ans below. You cannot remove int from array list , it should be object only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the exception message:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 18, size is 2
>   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>   at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:403)
>   at com.app.test.Activities.SuggestFilmActivity.onDelete(SuggestFilmActivity.java:222)

You are removing an element with index 18 in ArrayList which size is 2. And this exception occurs in onDelete method in SuggestFilmActivity class at line #222. So, based on your code what we have there:

```
public void onDelete(int Id) {
    if (usersListSend.size() > 0) {
        usersListSend.remove(Id);
    }

    Toast.makeText(context, "" + Id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

To fix this issue what I would suggest to do is this:

```
public void onDelete(int id) {
    if (id > -1 && id < usersListSend.size()) {
        usersListSend.remove(id);
    }

    Toast.makeText(context, "" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

***The id value must be greater than -1 and less than usersListSend.size()***

But the cause of the problem comes from here (it's from exception message):

> at
>   com.app.test.Adapters.SuggestFilm.SuggestFilmUserAdapter$2.onClick(SuggestFilmUserAdapter.java:76)

Go to the **SuggestFilmUserAdapter** class, find **line #76** and see what's going on there to completely resolve this issue.

In SuggestFilmUserAdapter class change this code:

```
//Cancel btn
holder.rowSuggestAddUser_cancelImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        deleteItem(position);
        deleteListener.onDelete(model.get(position).getId());
    }
});
```

To this one:

```
//Cancel btn
holder.rowSuggestAddUser_cancelImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = model.get(position).getId();
        deleteItem(position);
        deleteListener.onDelete(id);
    }
});
```

And modify this method:

```
private void deleteItem(int position) {
    model.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    //notifyItemRangeChanged(position, model.size()); // you notified already and no need to do it again I think
}
```

Removing SuggestFilmAddUser by its ID in SuggestFilmActivity class in method void onDelete(int Id):

```
@Override
public void onDelete(int Id) {
    if (usersListSend.size() > 0) usersListSend.remove(Integer.valueOf(Id)); // removing by Integer value not index!
    Toast.makeText(context, "" + Id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: hey, are you here my dear friend? if you here please tell me . please . thanks

Comment: If you see this message please answer to me

Comment: what's your question? I'll try to answer it

Comment: hey my friend do you see my messages?

Comment: hey my friend your answer help to me but show me strange error! can you connect to my PC with TeamViewer for see this? please

Comment: better if you create a new post with detailed info. You will get much more support from community. Right now I am not able to do what you asked me, sorry!

Comment: I try your code and work me and thanks for this <3 . but in your code for example I added users with this IDs : **18 - 127 - 26** . I added  users with this IDs . ok ? when delete user with this arrange **26 - 127 - 18** it's ok and not show me any error . (What ID first added, deleted last) . but When delete for Example with this arrange : **127 - 18 - 26 show me above error** . For **not show error I always deleted 18 finally** !!!! how can I fix this strange error my friend? please help me for this. please

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to store your `Id` as `String` in `ArrayList<String>` but i recommended you to read more about [ArrayList](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [Collections](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collection.html)

Comment: can you help me with my codes? please . I am amateur and really need you helps . please

Answer (score 0):

Replace int with Integer

```
public void onDelete(Integer Id) {
if (usersListSend.size() > 0) {
    usersListSend.remove(Id);
}

Toast.makeText(context, "" + Id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
```

Comment: That is wrong answer. You should read about [Autoboxing and Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Comment: Could you please explain why is wrong ans ?? I will really appreciate it

Comment: ok.... firstly you do not have to convert int primitive to wrapper object Integer, compiler will do unboxing and autoboxing. So, List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); list.add(1); list.add(2); is allright. Secondly, if you look to the source code of List interface you will see that remove method declared as follow: E remove(int index); thirdly your code does not resolve the issue

Comment: and also look at the overloaded method: boolean remove(Object o);

Comment: I would suggest you to make an experiment. Create any class, let's say Message. Create a list of messages: List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();. Add several values into messages list. And try to remove any item from that list: messages.remove(1); and messages.remove(Integer.valueOf(1)); and look at the result! You will get answer why your solution is wrong!

Comment: If i am creating my list List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>(); with Message type then why do i need to remove element like this  messages.remove(Integer.valueOf(1));. I can simply write messages.remove(messageObj).

Comment: In above question user Created list with Integer Type  private List<Integer> usersListSend = new ArrayList<>();  that is why i suggested to remove Integer instead of int.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158466/discussion-between-arbaz-rizvi-and-jibrahim).

Comment: Yes, I got it. You were right and I was confused. I thought that he used to remove item by index in a list and did not noticed that he uses List<Integer>. That was my fault and I sorry for that.